# File Attribute NSFileModificationDate returns time 5 hours after expected time in iPad application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, file, nsfilemanager

Hello I'm using the following NSFileManager method in an iPad application:

```
- (NSDictionary *)attributesOfItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
```

to get file attributes, then use the key NSFileModificationDate to get the latest file modification date/time.  However, the date/time that it is returning me is 5 hours ahead of the date that I actually save the file which is what I see inside my "Finder" when viewing properties of the file.

I know a workaround/hack would be to knock 5 hours of the time I get back but I'd like to know why this is happening.  Anybody know?  Thanks.

Comment: Time zones are fine on device and Mac

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember file timestamps are *always* in UTC, and the Finder compensates for whatever timezone you're currently in when displaying, so you have to do the same.

Comment: Thanks, I figured I'd eventually have to adjust myself but wasn't sure why.

Comment: What I had to do was use the localizedStringFromDate method from NSDateformatter.  I just sent it the date I got from the NSFileModificationDate key that took care of adjusting it for my timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Is this on-device or in the simulator? I'm guessing the latter since you refer to Finder in your question. In Simulator, the NSDate I get from the sample below doesn't give me a time zone. On-device behavior may be different; try it.

```
NSError * err;
NSFileManager * myManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString * myPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSDictionary * myDict = [myManager attributesOfItemAtPath:myPath error:&err];
NSDate * myDate = [myDict objectForKey:@"NSFileModificationDate"];
NSLog(@"%@", myDate);


2011-01-26 21:32:29.985 scraptime2[11488:207] 2011-01-27 03:32:27 +0000
```

(I would post a comment but I don't have enough rep yet)

Comment: It's actually happening on both.  Is that "+0000" thing the time zone?

Comment: Yeah.  If you run the same code on your Mac, it should give you the local date/time with the GMT adjustment applied.  From the Simulator I get out current GMT.  It sounds like you are too.

Comment: Looks like Rainer has brought some closure to this.  I just don't have a good citation for this other than what he said. I tried searching for UTC in the iOS docs (4.2) and found nothing useful.

Comment: These values come from the POSIX calls, where you'll find that file dates are always UTC-relative. Which makes sense, because when you take your laptop to a different timezone, they shouldn't change...